# ili9341 using 3 wire with stm32f030

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f0, development, ili9341

I am working with ili9341 TFT Display with STM32F0 MCU. And TFT display was connected with 3 configuration. 
I am confused between sending the "command" and "data" using spi communication.

So can anyone guide me, for sending "command" and "data" to TFT display using stm32's spi configuration. 
(Like I have make some pin high or low for "command" & "data" transferring)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry Dear Elliot,

Comment: This was not the "possible duplicate" of the same you mentioned in link.

Comment: This was the fresh & new problem that I was facing for development.

Comment: would be helpful to include the schematic/photo the wiring; the software environment you are using (arduino/stm32cube/HAL etc) and any code you have tried so far.